# XAMPP How do I allow simultaneous PHP queries from the same user/browser but different tabs?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am trying to run a PHP code that generate names, the result would be 3 million rows in the name database.

The name generator would take a list of name and loop itself based on the total number of names, the new name would be the combination of the first name and n-th name.

e.g
1. Dennis
2. Ben
3. Donald
4. R0nald

New names generated
Dennis Ben
Dennis Donald
Dennis Ronald
Ben Dennis
Ben Donald
Ben Ronald

I have split up the name generating script up to start from ID 1-500, 501-1000, 1001-1500 etc. 11 different PHP files.

Why does my CPU load stay at 3-5%, and my Harddisk % Highest Active Time is up to 45%.

What is this limit I don't know and how do I remove the limit?

Code:

```
$query = "query targetName FROM names";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
//$result will result in a 5273 row array

$total = mysqli_num_rows($result);


$table1 = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSELI_NUM)) {
$table[] = $row[0];
}

for ($i = 0; $i<$total; $i++) {
for ($x=0; $x<$total;$x++) {

if ($table1[$i] != $table1[$x]) {

$name = $table1[$i] . ' ' . $table1[$x];

$query = "INSERT INTO target (targetName, ...,...) VALUES ('...','...','...)"';
$results = mysqli_query($con,$query)

if ($result) {
echo "OK!";
}

else {
echo "fail!"
}

}
}
```

Comment: It's an easy script for PHP to run but the hard disk spike is because of the continuous inserting into the database. You could try inserting all in one query.

Comment: Please post the code that generates said output. Also, running it through a profiler would help track down the issue. Both the PHP code itself via xDebug or similar, and the HTTP requests via the browser.

Comment: I tried inserting using one query, but the CPU utilization never exceeds 5%. The HDD utilization hovers from 25-45%.

Comment: The code is as follows

http://pastebin.com/eLHsDiRp